# java using method error : they said "can not resolve symbol x"

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

[image]

```java
public class MethodExemple {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        MethodExemple methodExemple = new MethodExemple();
        methodExemple.StrCombine( x: "hello", y:"hongdroid");

        System.out.println(methodExemple.StrHongdroid( hong:"hollo"));

    }


    public void StrCombine (String x, String y) {
        String result = x + y;
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public String StrHongdroid (String hong, String droid){ 
        String result = hong +droid;
        return result;

    }
}
```

I coded as I learned in class. However, an error occurred only in my code. The contents of the error are as follows.

> cannot resolve symbol 'x' and 'y'

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

When calling a method in Java, you shouldn't specify the argument names, just provide them in order:

```java
methodExemple.StrCombine("hello", "hongdroid");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include x and y when calling the method StrCombine(). Here is the correct way methodExemple.StrCombine( "hello", "hongdroid"); either passing string literals like this or string variables